# How should I prepare a Linux virtual machine for others?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I'd like to share a VirtualBox virtual machine with a colleague, but would like to make sure this is tidied up before sending it on.

I guess I should include:

- SSH host keys
- DHCP leases
- files under `/etc/udev/rules.d/`
- any `.bash_history`

How should I do this? Have I missed anything important?

Comment: Are you asking how to turn a VM into a template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the libguestfs project's tool [virt-sysprep](http://libguestfs.org/virt-sysprep.1.html) is for.